# Making an image zoom when browser size is adjusted

Tags: javascript, css

i am trying to copy the looks of this site:

http://www.vindrejse.net/

If you try to re-size the window downwards, you can see that the image size re-sizes aswell, what exactly is done to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a jQuery plugin for exact this problem: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.fitpic.js

Here's an example for you: http://yckart.github.com/jquery.fitpic.js

Comment: tyvm, looking in to it now

Answer (score 0):

If you just worry about modern browsers, you can do that with CSS3's

```
background-size: cover;
```

declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to an industry standard for this is the BackStretch plugin:
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

It works on both full page backgrounds and DIV elements. Very simple configuration. Supports transitions.